# How to bind a value to “data-*” attribute using “bindAttr”?

Tags: html, sproutcore, handlebars.js

I’m trying to bind a value to a [custom `data-` attribute](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#attr-data) using `bindAttr` like this:

```
<a {{bindAttr data-foo="content.foo"}}>
```

This doesn’t seem to work as I get a parse error:

> ```
> Error: Parse error on line 16:
> ...}}         <a {{bindAttr data-foo="content.foo
> ----------------------^
> Expecting 'CLOSE', 'STRING', 'ID', 'SEP'
> ```

Using `dataFoo` instead works, though.

So is this not possible with SproutCore/Handlebars.js and I have to (ab-)use a different attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered just doing this:

```
<a data-foo="{{content.foo}}">
```